# C# WPF Increase value stored in TextBox as long as item is selected and decrease same amount when unselected

Tags: c#, wpf

my WPF App contains:

1x TextBox
1x ComboBox (2 items in it)
1x Button

Lets say the value of that TextBox is 100. IF first ComboBox item is selected and we use ClickEvent on that button, value from TextBox increases by 200. If second ComboBox item is selected, instead it increases by 100. ´

In this situation the value from TextBox is increasing non-stop with each button click.
How to hold that value at 300 or 200 (depending on ComboBox) regardless of times I click the button.

I don't really need a complete code for this but just a logic direction how to solve this without writing 187 lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to implement this depends on your requirements but the following sample code should give you the idea. It uses a variable to determine whether the value has already been increased:

```
private bool alreadyIncreased;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (alreadyIncreased)
        return;

    //1. Get the current value of the TextBox
    int.TryParse(tb.Text, out int value);

    //2. Increase the value based on the selected item
    if (cmb.Items.Count > 0 && cmb.SelectedItem == cmb.Items[0])
        value += 200;
    else
        value += 100;

    //3. Display the value in the TextBox
    tb.Text = value.ToString();
    alreadyIncreased = true;
}
```

You may want to reset the variable by for example handling the `SelectionChanged` event for the `ComboBox`.